# socket.io with nginx configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I am using `Socket.IO` on a Node server with Express and connection code of server side:

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Also client side connection like that:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script> 
var socket = io('https://example.com/example-service/');
```

And nginx conf is like that:

```
http { 
       upstream example-service {    
       server ip:8036;
      }
     server {
    listen 6583;


    #implementing WEB Socket
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://example-service/;
    }

    #my other application 
    location /test-app/ {
        proxy_pass  http://test-app/;
    }
 }
```

My socket connection code is in example-service and want to connect socket to other portal like test-app. If I given root path to socket service then its working proper. but if I passing nginx conf like that

```
# location /example-service/ {
    #     proxy_pass http://example-service/;
}
```

That time socket giving error 404.
Is there something I have to configure on client and server or Nginx?

Comment: Not getting your exact point, you want to say `/example-service` is not working but `/` is working?

Comment: yes right. '/' is root path of nginx, so cant pass root path there.